# map.on click is not working in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to click feature info on map click in openlayers3. I am getting error message in console like TypeError: layer.getSource(...) is null
my click function is

```
 map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var fl = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
        return { 'feature': feature, 'layer': layer };
    });

    var feature = fl.feature;
    layer = fl.layer;
    if (layer == vectorlayer) {
        var admin = "<table>";
        admin += "<tr><td style='color:green; border: 0px solid red;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;font-size:15px;'><b>  Information<b></td></tr>";
        admin += "<tr><td><b>Type</b></td><td>:</td><td >" + feature.get('field1') + "</td></tr>";
        admin += "<tr><td><b>District</b></td><td>:</td><td>" + feature.get('district') + "</td></tr>";
        admin += "<tr><td><b>Taluk</b></td><td>:</td><td >" + feature.get('taluk') + "</td></tr>";
        admin += "<tr><td><b>Village</b></td><td>:</td><td>" + feature.get('village') + "</td></tr>";
        admin += "<tr><td><b>code</b></td><td>:</td><td>" + feature.get('field2') + "</td></tr>";
        $("#Identifier").html(schooladmin);
        $("#Identifier").dialog('open');
        schooladmin += "</table>";
      }
});
```

Comment: how do you declare your layers??????  What sort of layers are they? Do they all have a proper source attached on them?????? Better make a fiddle to demonstarte your case

Answer (score 0):

That's not a click function, that's a pointermove function, if you want to use the click interaction you'll have to change the catched event to singleClick, like this :

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
   //...
});
```